# SQL2008 select row if last date hasnt updated in last 5 mins per unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that that continuously adds data every few seconds. There ishundreds of data populated with 90 eqpids. This is a sample:

```
Source_Date              | eqpId     
2016-02-10 10:39:45.397     3     
2016-02-10 10:37:45.317     2 
2016-02-10 10:37:46.307     6    
2016-02-10 10:36:45.257     5    
2016-02-10 10:33:42.397     4     
2016-02-10 10:32:41.397     3      
2016-02-10 10:31:44.397     1  
2016-02-10 10:29:49.397     5
```

I am looking for code to show data if the source_date has not updated in the last 5 mins but is unique to the eqpid.

it should show the below as these eqpid have not updated in last 5 mins.

```
Source_Date              | eqpId  
2016-02-10 10:33:42.397     4
2016-02-10 10:31:44.397     1
```

Comment: probably something like `select eqpid, max(source_data) from yourtable where eqpid not in (select distinct eqpid where source_date >= '5 minutes ago')`-type thing.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @TabAlleman it's clear and answerable and better than a lot of others though in my opinion. Perhaps you should have asked the OP what they had tried if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your records by `eqpId` and calculate `max(Source_Date)` for each `eqpId`.

Then just select records having difference from that value to current time greater than 5 minutes.

```
select
    max(Source_Date) as Source_Date,
    eqpId
from your_table
group by eqpId
having datediff(mi, max(Source_Date), getdate()) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`DATEADD`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function to get the timestamp of present time (which is [**`GETDATE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) in SQL Server) minus 5 minutes:

```
SELECT Source_Date, eqpId
FROM (
  SELECT Source_Date, eqpId,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY eqpId 
                            ORDER BY Source_date DESC) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  WHERE Source_Date > DATEADD(mi, -5, GETDATE()) ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

[**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) is used to select the most recent record per `eqpId` in case there are more than one records selected by the inner query.

Comment: thanks for the replys. really appreciate them. This shows the last record for every eqpid within the last 5 mins. Looking to just show a record for any eqpid that does not have a record within the last 5mins?